# Rails - drop down from an array of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu

I have an array like this:

```
['New York', 'Los Angeles']
```

And I want to be able to generate a select/option with those values in a form like this:

```
<%= form_tag filter_city_path, :method=> get do %>
  <%= select_tag "city", @list_of_cities %>
<% end %>
```

But this is not working. As you can see I want to pass the selection as **city** in the url.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use options_for_select helper like

```
<%= select_tag "city", options_for_select([['New York' ,'New york'], ['Los Angeles', 'Los Angeles']]) %>
```

Comment: Whenever possible, try and programmatically transform your arrays instead of spelling them out long-hand. You've illustrated why when not capitalizing 'york' in the second instance. `cities.collect { |c| [ c, c ] }` would do the job of expanding it.

Answer (score 6):

My method for this is to build the array as a constant in the model, force confirmation to options listed in the constant, and call it from the view

```
class Show < ApplicationRecord

  DAYS = [ "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday","friday", "saturday","sunday"]

  validates :day, inclusion: DAYS

end
```

If you want the option for that field to be submitted without content you'll have to call `allow_blank: true' in the validation as well. Once that is set up you can call the constant to populate the view in the form as so:

```
<%= select_tag "day", options_for_select(Show::DAYS) %>
```

or

```
<%= select_tag "day", options_for_select(Show::DAYS.sort) %>
```

if you want it presorted (which makes no sense with days of the week...)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your array doesn't have enough argument. Please refer to [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease).

The options typically needs to be formatted in this way:

```
[['Lisbon', 1], ['Madrid', 2], ...]
```

Take note the value `1`, `2`, etc.